# VC with UISlider to change textfield on VC2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uislider

I have a View controller that has a tableView embedded in a ContainerView and just below the ContainerView I have a UISlider. I have code on a view controller for the UISlider and code on another view controller that controls the table view.

Properties of the UISlider are set based on the selected text field - this section of code works. I am struggling to create a function/feature that will change the textField value when the UISlider is move. I think the UISlider Action needs to on the code that controls the UISlider, but I cannot determine how to cast the value of the UISlider.setvalue between the two viewController as the slider is moved to update the textField located in a tableCell. Hopefully makes some sense.

```
   // UISlider ViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sliderOutlet.isContinuous = true
    sliderOutlet.tintColor = UIColor.green
    self.refreshSlider()

}

@objc func refreshSlider() {
    sliderOutlet.minimumValue = Float(GlobalSliderValues.minimumValue)
    sliderOutlet.maximumValue = Float(GlobalSliderValues.maximumValue)
    sliderOutlet.value = Float(GlobalSliderValues.sliderValue)


//        if let chgIntValue = Int(GlobalSliderValues.changeValue)
//        { sliderOutlet.setValue(Float(Double(chgIntValue)), animated: true)
//        }

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refreshSlider), name: Notification.Name("refreshSlider"), object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("refreshSlider"), object: nil)
}
```

TableView Controller

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
mortgageAmount.addTarget(self, action: #selector(chgTextFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
}

@objc func chgTextFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField)
{

    if let chgStringValue = mortgageAmount.text
    {
        if Double(chgStringValue) ?? 1 > 10000 {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Input Error", message: "Value cannot be greater than 10000", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        GlobalSliderValues.minimumValue = 10
        GlobalSliderValues.maximumValue = 10000
        GlobalSliderValues.sliderValue = Int(mortgageAmount.text!)!
        GlobalSliderValues.mortageAmountValue = Float(Int(mortgageAmount.text!)!)

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:Notification.Name("refreshSlider"), object: nil)

        if let chgIntValue = Int(chgStringValue)
        { GlobalSliderValues.changeValue.setValue(Float(Double(chgIntValue)), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

    mortgageAmount.text = String(format: "%.2f",Double(sender.value))
}

   struct GlobalSliderValues {

        static var minimumValue = Int()
        static var maximumValue = Int()
        static var lowerValue = Int()
        static var UpperValue = Int()
        static var locationValue = Int()
        static var sliderValue = Int()
        static var sliderChgValue = ""


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need notification center to deal with refreshing the slider. Since we are using constants to store value your code can be changed as follows

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderOutlet: UISlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        sliderOutlet.isContinuous = true
        sliderOutlet.tintColor = UIColor.green

    }

    @objc func refreshSlider() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.sliderOutlet.minimumValue = Float(GlobalSliderValues.minimumValue)
            self.sliderOutlet.maximumValue = Float(GlobalSliderValues.maximumValue)
            self.sliderOutlet.value = Float(GlobalSliderValues.sliderValue)
            print(self.sliderOutlet.minimumValue)
            print(self.sliderOutlet.maximumValue)
            print(self.sliderOutlet.value)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.refreshSlider()
    }

}
```

I entered mortgage amount as so 1098 so slider look like below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the post. I think this code only works if the tableView and the UISlider are on the same view controller. The TableView inside a container View. My code is on two view controllers. One for the table view and the other for the UISlider.

Comment: I didn't mention anything like that. The view controller is a root view of the navigation controller and table view will be shown when clicking the edit button on view controller. Be clear what you want to update and how your view controllers are placed in a view